# Tab with in a Tab runtime error

Tags: android, xml, runtime, android-tabhost

I'm attempting to have embedded tab's and all looked fine until a runtime was thrown. I can't seem to see whats the problem although it probably lies in the XML - **Your TabHost must have a FrameLayout whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabcontent'**

```
com.example.dawnlp.mymap, PID: 23323
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dawnlp.mymap/com.example.dawnlp.mymap.Tab2Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your TabHost must have a FrameLayout whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabcontent'
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2977)
                                                                                      at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:136)
                                                                                      at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:348)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:764)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:423)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:193)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:645)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your TabHost must have a FrameLayout whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabcontent'
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabHost.setup(TabHost.java:202)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabHost.setup(TabHost.java:222)
                                                                                      at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:135)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:479)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2387)
                                                                                      at com.example.dawnlp.mymap.Tab2Activity.onCreate(Tab2Activity.java:28)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2977) 
                                                                                      at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:136) 
                                                                                      at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:348) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:764) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:423) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:193) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:645) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

My code

```
public class Tab2Activity extends TabActivity
{




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab2);

        /////////////////////////

        TabHost tabHost2 = getTabHost();

        TabHost.TabSpec Gmapped = tabHost2.newTabSpec("InnerTabs");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        Gmapped.setIndicator("", getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab3));
        Intent GmappedIntent = new Intent(this, Tab3Activity.class);
        GmappedIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Gmapped.setContent(GmappedIntent);

        tabHost2.addTab(Gmapped);
```

and tab.xml - I think the issue is here

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#332b2b"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dawnlp.mymap.Tab2Activity">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   >

        </TabWidget>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/veganfestival"

            android:text="Aberdeen"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6f844a" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/venue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Venue"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postcode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Postcode"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6f844a" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Vdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Vtime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6f844a" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blankagain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav"

            android:text="Take Me There"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"

            />


    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add framelayout in your xml file . Inside the framelayout add TabHost and other child elements.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#332b2b"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.dawnlp.mymap.Tab2Activity">

<FrameLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   >

    </TabWidget>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/veganfestival"

        android:text="Aberdeen"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"

        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#6f844a" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/venue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Venue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="City"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Postcode"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#6f844a" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Vdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Vtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#6f844a" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blankagain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nav"

        android:text="Take Me There"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"

        />


</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for that @sakikumar . But thrown error
Your TabHost must have a FrameLayout whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabcontent'

Comment: The
TabHost android:id="@android:id/android.R.id.tabhost" 

is showing an error

Comment: android:id="@android:id/tabhost"

Comment: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TabHost